# Changing colour of specified days in Android CalendarView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-custom-view, calendarview

I'm trying to change the text colour of specific days in Android's CalendarView to mark days that have events.

I'm currently trying to do this by making a copy of Android's CalendarView.java and injecting my own code in relevant places, but am open to other solutions.

So far I've copied the source CalendarView.java file into my project from `adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\sources\android-14\android\widget` and I'm trying to get it to work within my project but there are a lot of problems with R.styleable such as

```
TypedArray attributesArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CalendarView,
                R.attr.calendarViewStyle, 0);
        mShowWeekNumber = attributesArray.getBoolean(R.styleable.CalendarView_showWeekNumber,
                DEFAULT_SHOW_WEEK_NUMBER);
```

There also seems to be a declaration missing for mContext.  I've copied calendar_view.xml from `adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\platforms\android-15\data\res\layout`

Here are the errors that come up:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type 
styleable cannot be resolved or is not a field  CalendarView.java   /LoginActivity/src/uk/ac/bris/newtouch/newplan  line 369    Java Problem

styleable cannot be resolved or is not a field  CalendarView.java   /LoginActivity/src/uk/ac/bris/newtouch/newplan  line 368    Java Problem

styleable cannot be resolved or is not a field  CalendarView.java   /LoginActivity/src/uk/ac/bris/newtouch/newplan  line 374    Java Problem

styleable cannot be resolved or is not a field  CalendarView.java   /LoginActivity/src/uk/ac/bris/newtouch/newplan  line 371    Java Problem

styleable cannot be resolved or is not a field  CalendarView.java   /LoginActivity/src/uk/ac/bris/newtouch/newplan  line 362    Java Problem

styleable cannot be resolved or is not a field  CalendarView.java   /LoginActivity/src/uk/ac/bris/newtouch/newplan  line 359    Java Problem

styleable cannot be resolved or is not a field  CalendarView.java   /LoginActivity/src/uk/ac/bris/newtouch/newplan  line 366    Java Problem

styleable cannot be resolved or is not a field  CalendarView.java   /LoginActivity/src/uk/ac/bris/newtouch/newplan  line 364    Java Problem

calendar_view cannot be resolved or is not a field  CalendarView.java   /LoginActivity/src/uk/ac/bris/newtouch/newplan  line 400    Java Problem

mContext cannot be resolved CalendarView.java   /LoginActivity/src/uk/ac/bris/newtouch/newplan  line 398    Java Problem

mContext cannot be resolved to a variable   CalendarView.java    /LoginActivity/src/uk/ac/bris/newtouch/newplan line 1095   Java Problem

com.android.internal.R cannot be resolved to a variable CalendarView.java   /LoginActivity/src/uk/ac/bris/newtouch/newplan  line 404    Java Problem

list cannot be resolved or is not a field   CalendarView.java   /LoginActivity/src/uk/ac/bris/newtouch/newplan  line 403    Java Problem

mContext cannot be resolved to a variable   CalendarView.java   /LoginActivity/src/uk/ac/bris/newtouch/newplan  line 739    Java Problem

com.android.internal.R cannot be resolved to a variable CalendarView.java   /LoginActivity/src/uk/ac/bris/newtouch/newplan  line 376    Java Problem

TextAppearance_Small cannot be resolved or is not a field   CalendarView.java   /LoginActivity/src/uk/ac/bris/newtouch/newplan  line 374    Java Problem

com.android.internal.R cannot be resolved to a variable CalendarView.java   /LoginActivity/src/uk/ac/bris/newtouch/newplan  line 405    Java Problem

styleable cannot be resolved or is not a field  CalendarView.java   /LoginActivity/src/uk/ac/bris/newtouch/newplan  line 382    Java Problem

mContext cannot be resolved to a variable   CalendarView.java    /LoginActivity/src/uk/ac/bris/newtouch/newplan line 1035   Java Problem

styleable cannot be resolved or is not a field  CalendarView.java   /LoginActivity/src/uk/ac/bris/newtouch/newplan  line 378    Java Problem

mContext cannot be resolved to a variable   CalendarView.java   /LoginActivity/src/uk/ac/bris/newtouch/newplan  line 1034   Java Problem

error: Error: Resource is not public. (at 'id' with value '@+android:id/month_name').   calendar_view.xml   /LoginActivity/res/layout   line 25 Android AAPT Problem

styleable cannot be resolved or is not a field  CalendarView.java   /LoginActivity/src/uk/ac/bris/newtouch/newplan  line 346    Java Problem

LocaleData cannot be resolved   CalendarView.java   /LoginActivity/src/uk/ac/bris/newtouch/newplan  line 347    Java Problem

styleable cannot be resolved or is not a field  CalendarView.java   /LoginActivity/src/uk/ac/bris/newtouch/newplan  line 348    Java Problem

styleable cannot be resolved or is not a field  CalendarView.java   /LoginActivity/src/uk/ac/bris/newtouch/newplan  line 352    Java Problem

error: Error: Resource is not public. (at 'id' with value '@+android:id/day_names').    calendar_view.xml   /LoginActivity/res/layout   line 33 Android AAPT Problem

styleable cannot be resolved or is not a field  CalendarView.java   /LoginActivity/src/uk/ac/bris/newtouch/newplan  line 342    Java Problem

calendarViewStyle cannot be resolved or is not a field  CalendarView.java   /LoginActivity/src/uk/ac/bris/newtouch/newplan  line 343    Java Problem

styleable cannot be resolved or is not a field  CalendarView.java   /LoginActivity/src/uk/ac/bris/newtouch/newplan  line 344    Java Problem
```

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this?

Comment: Related/dupe: [Android CalendarView for Showing Events](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16556254)